# Python: Split text with emojis as delimiters

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to split a WhatsApp chat text into single words, but I don't know how to use the unicode of the emojis as additional delimiters.

According to http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html, an example unicode would be U+1F602. I tried the following, but it doesn't work.

```
text = file.read()
delimiters = " ", "..", "\"", "<", ">", "/", u"U+1F602"
regexPattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, delimiters))
list = re.split(regexPattern, text)
```

Comment: What python version? Define doesn't work. Here (python2.7.11+) this snippet (https://gist.github.com/lauromoura/f46442e25d1e08519af4aaef972cad3b) worked fine, splitting all letters. Maybe something related to the input string?

Comment: ok, I am using Python 2.7.10, maybe that's why it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

The literal for a non-BMP Unicode character is NOT `u"U+1F602"`, it is `u"\U0001F602"` in Python.

Though (by itself) it is not enough to fix the regex. Pass `flags=re.UNICODE` to `re.split()`. Make sure `type(text)` is `unicode`.

> I am trying to split a WhatsApp chat text into single words

You could try `words = re.findall(ur"\w+", text, flags=re.UNICODE)`. In general, how a text can be split into parts may depend on context e.g., see [how `nltk.tokenize.TweetTokenizer` is implemented](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/casual.html#TweetTokenizer).

Answer (score 1):

`u"U+1F602"` is not a unicode character, try printing it, what you meant was `unichr(0x1f602)`